# I want to print User ID but in this place print is "System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader"

Tags: c#, winforms

print User ID but in this place print is

> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataReader

```
try
{
    con = new SqlConnection(cs.DBConn);
    con.Open();
    String sql = "SELECT SSUserID from SSUserInformation where UserName like '"
        + txtUserName.Text + "%'";
    cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, con);
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection);
    frm.lbluserid.Text = Convert.ToString(rdr);

    con.Close();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message, "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK
        , MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Are you expecting more than one row? ExecuteScalar instead?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`Convert.ToString(rdr);`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh(v=vs.110).aspx) returns the full type name of `SqlDataReader` since it is equivalent to `rdr.GetType().ToString()`(last sentence of the remarks section [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/astxcyeh(v=vs.110).aspx)).

Instead you want following:

```
if(rdr.Read())
    frm.lbluserid.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
```

But as mentioned by Rup in the comment you could also use [`ExecuteScalar`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.executescalar(v=vs.110).aspx) if the query always returns a single value.

```
frm.lbluserid.Text = Convert.ToString(cmd.ExecuteScalar());
```

Answer (score 2):

try below code :-

```
while (rdr.Read())
{
     frm.lbluserid.Text = rdr.GetString(0);
}
```

As documented here :- http://www.csharp-station.com/Tutorial/AdoDotNet/lesson04

> As explained earlier, the SqlDataReader returns data via a sequential
>   stream. To read this data, you must pull data from a table row-by-row
>   Once a row has been read, the previous row is no longer available. To
>   read that row again, you would have to create a new instance of the
>   SqlDataReader and read through the data stream again.
>
> The typical method of reading from the data stream returned by the
>   SqlDataReader is to iterate through each row with a while loop.

**Extra Note** :-

I would recommend you to use Command.ExecuteReader to get just on value from the database. Instead, you should use Command.ExecuteScalar as following:

```
frm.lbluserid.Text = (String) cmd.ExecuteScalar();
```